# Xamarin forms notification registration is not working

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms

In my Xamarin forms application I need to implement notification in iOS.I have added following code in the Appdelegate class.

```
if (UIDevice.CurrentDevice.CheckSystemVersion(8, 0))
        {
            var pushSettings = UIUserNotificationSettings.GetSettingsForTypes(
                               UIUserNotificationType.Alert | UIUserNotificationType.Badge | UIUserNotificationType.Sound,
                               new NSSet());

            UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterUserNotificationSettings(pushSettings);
            UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterForRemoteNotifications();
        }
        else {

            UIRemoteNotificationType notificationTypes = UIRemoteNotificationType.Alert | UIRemoteNotificationType.Badge | UIRemoteNotificationType.Sound | UIRemoteNotificationType.None | UIRemoteNotificationType.NewsstandContentAvailability;
            UIApplication.SharedApplication.RegisterForRemoteNotificationTypes(notificationTypes);

        }
```

But RegisteredForRemoteNotifications is not calling in my application.I have also enabled the Remote Notifications in info.plist.

```
  public override void RegisteredForRemoteNotifications(UIApplication application, NSData deviceToken)
    {
    }
```

Comment: What is your target in the iOS project. Are you receiving any error with the code above?

Comment: Deployment Target is 8.0 and my testing device is 9.1

Comment: Did you select the good profile in the project properties?

Comment: yes..otherwise an error message will show.

Comment: I'm not sure if it is the right place to call this code on AppDelegate. I'm calling this code after a user logins to my App through my Login Content Page. If login succeeds than i call this code and everything works fine. If you do not have such a workflow, you can override OnAppearing() method of your first ContentPage and call it there.